# How to add GWTP plugin in MyEclipse 8.6?

Tags: gwt, myeclipse, gwtp

I am starting a new project using GWTP framework. But getting stucked while adding GWT plugin in MyEclipse 8.6. Googled a lot, but couldn't get a proper solution.

I tried to install it from Menu Help --> MyEclipse Configuration Center --> Software. But I am getting the error : "**Changes cannot be applied for MyEclipse 8.6 at this time.Please shut down other processes using this profile or update from other processes.No lock could be obtained.**"

I checked the processses as well. There is only one process running for MyEclipse,from where I am trying to install the plugin.

Can you please help me out?

Any references would be appreciated.

Thanks,in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what causes that error but 8.6 is pretty old and no longer supported. Error may be related to the back end support for adding plugins from MyEclipse servers is no longer there. Try adding an update site, to install from. Though, best to update to latest release. In any case, make sure the GWTP plugin is compatible with the underlying eclipse release for the MyEclipse release you're using.